# Average force exerted by object dropped onto floor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

### Question :

A 2.0 kg mud ball drops from rest at a height of 15 m. If the impact between the
ball and the ground lasts 0.50 s, what is the average force exerted by the ball
on the ground

---

### working

I have this setup :

[image]

Taking gravity $ g = 10 $.

At $A$ potential energy $ = mgh = 15(10)(2) = 300$.

Using Conservation of energy as:

$$
W + PE_0 + KE_0 = 
PE_f + KE_f + \text{Energy(Lost)}
$$

Where all energies other than $PE$ and $KE$ are zero gives

$$
PE_A = KE_B
$$

So that the kinetic energy when impact starts is equal to the initial potential
energy, which is $300$.

From this we can find the velocity as

$$
KE = \frac{1}{2}mv^2
$$

Meaning

$$
v = \sqrt{300} \approx 17.32
$$

Using Impulse momentum theorem we have

$$
I = F \Delta t = \Delta p = m (v_1 - v_0)
$$

Here $v_0 = 0$ and $v_1$ has been found as $\sqrt{300}$.

From this we have

$$
F \Delta t
=
m(\sqrt{300})
$$

And

$$
F =
\frac{m\sqrt{300}}{\Delta t}
$$

Here $\Delta t = 0.5$ then the average force exerted is $F = 4\sqrt{300} = 40
\sqrt{3} \approx 69.28$

Therefore the average force exerted is $69.28$ to 2 decimal places

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @Farcher the question is stated at the top. My working is what I'm not confident with and I don't have any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the velocity at the bottom of the height. That comes out to be √(300) .also note that this would also be the velocity with which the ball bounces back up . so if you want to find the force exerted by the ball on the ground. Find the change in velocity and apply 
F =m (v1-v2)/t 
The answer would be double of what you got or 138.56

Comment: I used that formula though?  I thought so at least. At which part are you referring to find the change in velocity at?

Comment: When it is just about to hit the ground its velocity is √(300) downward and later its √(300) upward. Thus change in velocity would be  2*√(300)

Comment: Thanks - I've considered the initial velocity as zero , but you're right, I should have considered the velocity change from before to after the impact. I'll try and write it up nicely.